# Maximum and Minimum values for ints

Tags: python, integer

How do I represent minimum and maximum values for integers in Python? In Java, we have `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

---

<sub>See also: [What is the maximum float in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283).</sub>

Comment: Note that in Python 3 the `int` type is basically the same as the `long` type in Python 2, so the idea of a maximum or minimum `int` disappears completely. It's basically irrelevant even on Python 2.

Comment: @agf: it can be relevant in various way. For instance in any algorithm that require to save the min value found (like a sorting algorithm). The min value could be initialized at sys.maxint so it guarantees that any first value found is taken as min

Comment: @Toaster except that you can have a list where all values are greater than `sys.maxint` since it's only the maximum for the `int` type on Python 2, which Python will silently promote to a `long`.

Comment: If you need to use "a very large value" in an algorithm, e.g. finding minimum or maximum of a generic collection, `float('inf')` or `float('-inf')` can be quite helpful.

Comment: @geoff true, but one caveat for modern code is that floats can't be used as `Literal` in type hints. So you can't say that a list can contain `Union[int, Literal[-inf]]` even though that might be exactly what might be needed for a given application :/

Comment: Might worth reading: [\[SO\]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546).

Answer (score 1293, accepted):

#### Python 3

In Python 3, this question doesn't apply. The plain `int` type is unbounded.

However, you might actually be looking for information about the current interpreter's *[word size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes)*, which will be the same as the machine's word size in most cases. That information is still available in Python 3 as [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize), which is the maximum value representable by a signed word. Equivalently, it's the size of the largest possible list or in-memory sequence.

Generally, the maximum value representable by an unsigned word will be `sys.maxsize * 2 + 1`, and the number of bits in a word will be `math.log2(sys.maxsize * 2 + 2)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6918334/577088) for more information.

#### Python 2

In Python 2, the maximum value for plain `int` values is available as [`sys.maxint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint):

```
>>> sys.maxint  # on my system, 2**63-1
9223372036854775807
```

You can calculate the minimum value with `-sys.maxint - 1` as shown [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint).

Python seamlessly switches from plain to long integers once you exceed this value. So most of the time, you won't need to know it.

Comment: This number may appear to be arbitrary, but it isn't. 9223372036854775807 is exactly `2^63 - 1`, so you've got a 64-bit int. In general, an n-bit integer has values ranging from `-2^(n-1)` to `2^(n-1) - 1`.

Comment: Note that if you're using a 32-bit Python runtime, sys.maxint will return `2^31 - 1`, even though Python will jump to 64-bit seamlessly with the `long` datatype.

Comment: Use `sys.maxsize` instead, as suggested by @Akash Rana. It is present also in Python 2, [as `sys` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) say. This will make the code more compatible with both Python versions.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis, are you 100% certain the values are the same for all systems and implementations? Until I find something that convinces me that they are, I'm inclined not to make any assumptions.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee for equality. However, [the docs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13795777/1959808) say that these are typically equal, and recommends the replacement, which `2to3` [applies](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-renames).

Comment: You and I have different interpretations of that line from the docs. The replacement in `2to3` is a fine quick-and-dirty heuristic that won't break anything most of the time -- but the difference between these two values matters. The best practice is to use the value you actually mean to use. If you _truly need_ `sys.maxint` in Python 2, you won't need it anymore in Python 3, and it should really be removed entirely, not changed to `sys.maxsize`.

Comment: minsize - Multiplying with Bitwise min operator gives minsize

~sys.maxsize

Comment: If there is anybody curious why the maximum positive integer encodable is `2^63 - 1` for 64 bit and `2^31 - 1` for 32 bit checkout this post http://davidalbertoadler.com/twos-complement

Comment: Also [`sys.int_info`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.int_info) might be of interest.

Comment: for the minimum value, why we need `-1` after `-sys.maxsize` ?

Comment: @DerekFan because like almost all modern computing platforms, Python uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Basically, you have an even number of possible values, and zero takes up a slot among the positive values, so there is one more negative value than nonzero positive value.

Comment: @DerekFan I should add that it's not just that Python uses two's complement; I'm pretty sure that happens at the level of the processor itself.

Comment: @MarcoSulla are you saying there's a difference between the maximum array size and the machine's word size? I was not under that impression. I'm inclined to add details if that's the case, rather than simply changing the nomenclature without clarification.

Comment: @senderle: I linked the official source of the Python docs. Word size are typically 32 or 64 bit, while `Py_ssize_t` is typical `2**31 - 1` or `2**63 - 1`.

Comment: @MarcoSulla I think it's splitting hairs to distinguish between the number of bits in a word and the maximum value representable by a word. It's two different ways of measuring the same thing. Also, the docs specifically refer to `sys.maxsize` as the [best place to look for the word sizes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.architecture).

Comment: The docs you linked says that, if you want to know if the Py interpreter is 64 bit, you can do check `sys.maxsize > 2**32`. Indeed, as I wrote and documented, on 32 bit `sys.maxsize` is `2**31-1`. I repeat, `sys.maxsize` is *not* the machine word size, it's the size of the CPython [Py_ssize_t](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/) type, that's a bit different from `size_t`

Comment: OK, yes I see you're talking about the distinction between signed and unsigned. I changed the answer to reflect that distinction.

Comment: <<I changed the answer to reflect that distinction.>> :-)

Comment: There is still a maximum integer size in python 3. It is just limited by memory allocation bounds rather than cpu instruction bounds. `1 << sys.maxsize` immediately throws an exception. I was curious how to find the allocaiton limit.

Comment: CPython 3 ints [are bounded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76136809) by the 63-bit integer that stores how many 30-bit unsigned "sub"-integers the int is made out of. In practice they are bounded by how much RAM your computer has.

Comment: sys.min_int would be welcome too...

Answer (score 515):

If you just need a number that's bigger than all others, you can use

```
float('inf')
```

in similar fashion, a number smaller than all others:

```
float('-inf')
```

This works in both python 2 and 3.

Comment: Just a note tho (as irrelevant it is, but still): float('inf') > float('inf') results in 'false'. Infinite number should be bigger than another infinite number :-D ... *mind snaps*

Comment: @Scre What else would you expect?  `x > x` is usually `False`, and infinity should be no exception. (`float('NaN)`, on the other hand...)

Comment: This actually doesn't apply for `int` cauze `cannot convert infinite float to int`...but works for most cases

Comment: @Scre "In comparison operations, positive infinity is larger than all values except itself and NaN, and negative infinity is smaller than all values except itself and NaN."

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP question

Comment: @ghosh maybe not but it answered the question the OP likely had. In Java (and similar) if you want to keep track of a min for example) you can start by storing the max int so that anything else is less than it. In Python you can achieve the same behavior using `float('inf')`, and it works because `float('inf') > a` for any `int` `a`, and since the type of `a` can change freely, you can just set `a = min(a, b)`

Comment: However, in `float('inf') > float('inf')`, could we consider the second float the same number as the first float (itself) and thus is the case of being itself?

Comment: @Scre nope, in maths two (countable at least) infinities are equal, example: series of 1,2,3,..,n is of the same size as 2,4,6,...,2n. Hence float(inf) > float(int) must be False, because float(inf) == float(inf) is proven to be true

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. If he needs to limit his ints to the system max size this won't cut it.

Answer (score 315):

The **`sys.maxint`** constant [has been removed from Python 3.0 onward](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers), instead use **`sys.maxsize`**.

> #### Integers
>
> - **[PEP 237](https://peps.python.org/pep-0237/)**: Essentially, `long` renamed to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). That is, there is only one built-in integral type, named `int`; but it behaves mostly like the old `long` type.
>
> ...
>
> - The `sys.maxint` constant was removed, since there is no longer a limit to the value of integers. However, [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) can be used as an integer larger than any practical list or string index. It conforms to the implementation’s “natural” integer size and is typically the same as `sys.maxint` in previous releases on the same platform (assuming the same build options).

Comment: Correct. Indeed, from `help(sys)`: *maxsize -- the largest supported length of containers*. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I guess that the correct answer depends on the use case: in my casa (a default for a limiting parameter in a function) this was indeed the best answer, YMMV.

Answer (score 123):

For Python 3, there is no maximum or minimum value for the `int` type.

You might be interested in [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) instead. According to the documentation:

> sys.maxsize
>
> An integer giving the maximum value a variable of type `Py_ssize_t` can
> take. It’s usually `2**31 - 1` on a 32-bit platform and `2**63 - 1` on a
> 64-bit platform.

```py
import sys
max_size = sys.maxsize
min_size = -sys.maxsize - 1
```

Comment: well, python 3 does _exist_ , thankfully(!); but `sys.maxint` doesn't exist in python 3 (tl;dr:  _"`sys.maxint` constant was removed (in python3), since there is no longer a limit to the value of integers. However, `sys.maxsize` can be used as an integer larger than any practical list or string index."_ )

Comment: for the minimum value, why we need `-1` after `-sys.maxsize` ?

Comment: Look up 2’s compliment binary

Comment: `min = ~sys.maxsize`

Comment: What is the bit value of your equation? What happens when you subtract one? Which result is more negative?

Comment: Here, you go.  Count the number of binary digits.  `print(bin(sys.maxsize))
0b111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
print(bin(-sys.maxsize))
-0b111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
print(bin(-sys.maxsize-1))
-0b1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: This answer is false.  If it were true `sys.maxsize ** 2` would not return a valid and correct value, yet it does.  You should delete this answer.

Comment: These would work great as sentinel values in algorithms, which is a common usage. Please don’t delete this answer, just make it clear that it’s the most practical one, even if not the most mathematically correct one.

Comment: Why would you care to subtract 1 when there is really no minimum value in Python 3?

Answer (score 93):

In Python 2, integers will automatically switch from a fixed-size `int` representation into a variable width [`long`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.long_info) representation once you pass the value [`sys.maxint`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.maxint), which is either 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 or 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 depending on your platform. Notice the `L` that gets appended here:

```
>>> 9223372036854775807
9223372036854775807
>>> 9223372036854775808
9223372036854775808L
```

From the [Python 2.7 manual](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric):

> Numbers are created by numeric literals or as the result of built-in functions and operators. Unadorned integer literals (including binary, hex, and octal numbers) yield plain integers unless the value they denote is too large to be represented as a plain integer, in which case they yield a long integer. Integer literals with an `'L'` or `'l'` suffix yield long integers (`'L'` is preferred because `1l` looks too much like eleven!).

Python tries very hard to pretend its integers are mathematical integers and are unbounded. It can, for instance, calculate a [googol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Googol.html) with ease:

```
>>> 10**100
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L
```

Comment: To add to the confusion, Python's `long` isn't like Java's `long` - it's rather closer to `BigInteger`.

Comment: In python3, seems there is no `L` suffix, and it's just `int`, not `long`, no matter how large the number is.

Comment: may i suggest editing your answer showing `type(...)` instead on relying on an `L` at the end which an have ambiguous meaning?

Comment: @JohnD What is the ambiguity?

Answer (score 30):

You may use 'inf' like this:

```
import math
bool_true = 0 < math.inf
bool_false = 0 < -math.inf
```

Refer: [math — Mathematical functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

Comment: Note that `math.inf` is equivalent to `float('inf')`

Comment: The author questioned how to obtain the MAX and MIN int values. How does this answer relates to the question, since the results are True and False, not MAX and MIN?

Comment: Be aware that `math.inf` and `-math.inf` cannot be converted into int, e.g. this will fail: `a = math.inf; b = int(a)`. It will throw `OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer`. You can use it, but be aware it is outside the number range of `int`. So you can't use it as a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Answer (score 10):

If you want the max for array or list indices (equivalent to `size_t` in C/C++), you can use numpy:

```
np.iinfo(np.intp).max
```

This is same as `sys.maxsize` however advantage is that you don't need import sys just for this.

If you want max for native int on the machine:

```
np.iinfo(np.intc).max
```

You can look at other available types in [doc](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.01-understanding-data-types.html).

For floats you can also use `sys.float_info.max`.

Comment: e.g. for the maximum 32-bit int use: `np.iinfo(np.int32).max`

Answer (score 6):

`sys.maxsize` is not the actually the maximum integer value which is supported. You can double maxsize and multiply it by itself and it stays a valid and correct value.

However, if you try `sys.maxsize ** sys.maxsize`, it will hang your machine for a significant amount of time. As many have pointed out, the byte and bit size does not seem to be relevant because it practically doesn't exist. I guess python just happily expands it's integers when it needs more memory space. So in general there is no limit.

Now, if you're talking about packing or storing integers in a safe way where they can later be retrieved with integrity then of course that is relevant.  I'm really not sure about packing but I know python's `pickle` module handles those things well. String representations obviously have no practical limit.

So really, the bottom line is: what is your applications limit?  What does it require for numeric data?  Use that limit instead of python's fairly nonexistent integer limit.

Answer (score 5):

On CPython 3.11 on a 64-bit system, the maximum and minimal integers are

```py
  2 ** ((2 ** 63 - 1) * 30) - 1
-(2 ** ( 2 ** 63      * 30) - 1)
```

You will need [40 exabytes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=64+%2B+64+%2B+64+%2B+32+*+%282%5E63+-+1%29+bits) of memory to create one, which would cost [$70 billion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%2864+%2B+64+%2B+64+%2B+32+*+%282%5E63+-+1%29+bits%29+%2F+%2832GB+%2F+%2456.99%29) at today's (July 2023) prices of $57 per 32GB [on NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?Order=1&N=601275376%20100007611), so in practice Python's maximum integer is limited by how much memory you have in your computer.

---

CPython 3.11 stores integers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365639) (I simplified the actual code by taking out all the macros):

```c
struct PyLongObject {
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;  /* Metadata for garbage collection */
    PyTypeObject* ob_type; /* Metadata for type() */
    Py_ssize_t ob_size;    /* Number of items in ob_digit */
    uint32_t ob_digit[1];  /* Array of 32-bit integers */
};
```

So on a 64-bit system, Python integers are implemented as an array of 32-bit integers storing the absolute value of the integer (but 2 of the bits of each integer [aren't used](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/86ef1ce1217eefbe005f61d76fa1f7a3aa01b74e/Include/cpython/longintrepr.h#L12-L13)) and a 64-bit signed [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer stores the length of that array as well as the sign of the Python integer, so a negative integer has a negative "size".

Answer (score 4):

I rely heavily on commands like this.

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.maxsize)'
```

Max int returned: **9223372036854775807**

For more references for 'sys' you should access

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize

Comment: No - maxsize is simply the largest possible container index. Python will happily work with 100 digit integers and more

Answer (score 2):

As other answers point out, unlike `float` (which has the maximum value of `sys.float_info.max`), `int` type is unbounded in Python; it is really bounded by the memory limit of your machine. That said, there are some limits related to integers.

For example, since Python 3.10.7, converting `str` to `int` or printing `int` is limited to 4300 digits, a consequence of which is writing a very long integer to a file is limited by default (which can be turned off by running `sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)`). You can get information about the internal representation of integers in Python using `sys.int_info`.

Also since `float` is bounded, you can't perform calculations where the output would become a float that is outside float bound (e.g. `2**1025/2` raises an `OverflowError`).

Also, `int` in popular data analysis libraries such as numpy and pandas etc. are bound by their type, e.g. `numpy.uint64` can hold the largest positive integer in numpy, which can be checked by `np.iinfo('uint64')`. This means we can't perform vectorized computations involving too large integers, e.g. we can't take log2 of 2**64 (in fact, `np.log2(2**64)` raises a TypeError).

`sys.maxsize` is the size of the largest possible list. You can check that by using `range()`.

```py
len(range(sys.maxsize)) == sys.maxsize    # 9223372036854775807
len(range(sys.maxsize+1))                 # OverflowError
```

Answer (score -3):

code given below will help you.
for maximum value you can use **sys.maxsize** and for minimum you can **negate** same value and use it.

```
import sys 

ni=sys.maxsize
print(ni)
```