# "sys.getsizeof(int)" returns an unreasonably large value?

Tags: python

I want to check the size of int data type in python:

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(int)
```

It comes out to be "436", which doesn't make sense  to me. 
Anyway, I want to know how many bytes (2,4,..?) int will take on my machine.

Comment: Note that python has support for very large numbers, which means you almost certainly won't get 2 or 4 or something even close. What are you *really* trying to do? Figure out if you're running a 32-bit or 64-bit OS/CPU?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

#### The short answer

You're getting the size of the *class*, not of an instance of the class. Call `int` to get the size of an instance:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(int())
28
```

If that size still seems a little bit large, remember that a Python `int` is very different from an `int` in (for example) C. In Python, an `int` is a fully-fledged object. This means there's extra overhead.

Every Python object contains at least a refcount and a reference to the object's type in addition to other storage; on a 64-bit machine, just those two things alone take up 16 bytes! The `int` internals (as determined by the standard CPython implementation) have also changed over time, so that the amount of additional storage taken depends on your version.

#### `int` objects in CPython 3.11

Integer objects are internally [`PyLongObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLongObject) C types representing blocks of memory. The [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba16324b276c7b2b5ecf09479f30fc82c12192ae/Include/pytypedefs.h#L19) [that](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba16324b276c7b2b5ecf09479f30fc82c12192ae/Include/cpython/longintrepr.h#L82-L85) [defines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba16324b276c7b2b5ecf09479f30fc82c12192ae/Include/object.h#L92) [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba16324b276c7b2b5ecf09479f30fc82c12192ae/Include/object.h#L109-L112) [type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba16324b276c7b2b5ecf09479f30fc82c12192ae/Include/pytypedefs.h#L18) is [spread](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba16324b276c7b2b5ecf09479f30fc82c12192ae/Include/object.h#L100-L104) [across](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba16324b276c7b2b5ecf09479f30fc82c12192ae/Include/object.h#L72) multiple files. Here are the relevant parts:

```c
typedef struct _longobject PyLongObject;

struct _longobject {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    digit ob_digit[1];
};

#define PyObject_VAR_HEAD      PyVarObject ob_base;

typedef struct {
    PyObject ob_base;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
} PyVarObject;

typedef struct _object PyObject;

struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    union {
       Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P > 4
       PY_UINT32_T ob_refcnt_split[2];
#endif
    };
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
};

/* _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA is nothing on non-debug builds */
#  define _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA

typedef uint32_t digit;
```

If we expand all the [macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html) and replace all the `typedef` statements, this is the struct we end up with:

```c
struct PyLongObject {
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
    uint32_t ob_digit[1];
};
```

`uint32_t` means "unsigned 32-bit integer" and `uint32_t ob_digit[1];` means an array of 32-bit integers is used to hold the (absolute) value of the integer. The "`1`" in "`ob_digit[1]`" means the array should be initialized with space for 1 element.

So we have the following bytes to store an integer object in Python (on a 64-bit system):

- 8 bytes (64 bits, `Py_ssize_t`, signed) for `ob_refcnt` - the [reference count](https://devguide.python.org/internals/garbage-collector/)
- 8 bytes (64 bits, `PyTypeObject*`) for `ob_type` - the pointer to the `int` class itself
- 8 bytes (64 bits, `Py_ssize_t`, signed) for `ob_size` - which stores how many 32-bit integers are used to store the integer

and finally a variable-length array (with at least 1 element) of

- 4 bytes (32 bits) to store each part of the integer

The [comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/86ef1ce1217eefbe005f61d76fa1f7a3aa01b74e/Include/cpython/longintrepr.h#L64-L80) that accompanies this definition summarizes Python 3.11's representation of integers. Zero is represented not by an object with size (`ob_size`) zero (the *actual* size is always at least 1 though). Negative numbers are represented by objects with a negative size attribute! This [comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/86ef1ce1217eefbe005f61d76fa1f7a3aa01b74e/Include/cpython/longintrepr.h#L11-L17) further explains that only 30 bits of each `uint32_t` [are](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/86ef1ce1217eefbe005f61d76fa1f7a3aa01b74e/Include/cpython/longintrepr.h#L12-L15) [used](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/86ef1ce1217eefbe005f61d76fa1f7a3aa01b74e/Include/cpython/longintrepr.h#L61-L62) for storing the value.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(0)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(2 ** 30 - 1)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(2 ** 30)
32
>>> sys.getsizeof(2 ** 60 - 1)
32
>>> sys.getsizeof(2 ** 60)
36
```

On CPython 3.10 and older, `sys.getsizeof(0)` incorrectly returns 24 instead of 28, this was a bug that [was fixed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/358b02dac478b9ce379ab5982400bb8ecf11a2ee#diff-1a6e70e2beeecad88840c67284ac4d54a36998029244771fcc820e801390726aR5670-R5671). Python 2 had a second, [separate type of integer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) which worked a bit differently, but generally similar.

You will get slightly different results on a 32-bit system.

Comment: Thanks! But my system returns 12 for the size. Is that in bytes? Kinda larger than I thought if it is in bytes, and unreasonable if in bits...

Comment: @HailiangZhang, that's 12 bytes -- or 24 bytes in my case. A Python int is very different from an int in (for example) c. In Python, an `int` is a fully-fledged object. This means there's extra overhead. See [here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/) for a fairly detailed discussion of the (cpython) `int` internals.

Comment: @HailiangZhang, also, [this](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html) describes the structure of the `PyObject_HEAD` macro that you see in the page linked to above. Every Python object contains at least a refcount and a reference to the object's type in addition to other storage.

Comment: If you want to store a large number of compactly-stored 32-bit (or fewer-bit) integers, see the `array` module.