# Possible to store Python ints in less than 12 bytes?

Tags: python, int

Is it possible to make Python use less than 12 bytes for an int?

```
>>> x=int()
>>> x
0
>>> sys.getsizeof(x)
12
```

I am not a computer specialist but isn't 12 bytes excessive?

The smallest int I want to store is 0, the largest int 147097614, so I shouldn't really need more than 4 bytes.

(There is probably something I misunderstand here as I couldn't find an answer anywhere on the net. Keep that in mind.)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365624/sys-getsizeofint-returns-an-unreasonably-large-value).

Comment: Thanks. Interesting info there, but luckily not a duplicate, AFAICS.

Comment: If you think 12 bytes is excessive, wait till you try it on a 64-bit architecture where it takes 24 bytes!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In python, `int`s are objects just like everything else.  Because of that, there is a little extra overhead just associated with the fact that you're using an object which has some associated meta-data.

If you're going to use *lots* of ints, and it makes sense to lay them out in an array-like structure, you should look into `numpy`.  Numpy `ndarray` objects will have a little overhead associated with them for the various pieces of meta-data that the array objects keep track of, but the actual data is stored as the datatype you specify (e.g. `numpy.int32` for a 4-byte integer.)

Thus, if you have:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(5000,dtype=np.int32)
```

The array will take only slightly more than `4*5000 = 20000` bytes of your memory

Comment: A good answer; note that it's not necessary to depend on numpy to efficiently store a large amount of integers. The `array` module offers a lightweight (but less featureful) alternative and is available in the standard library.

Answer (score 7):

Size of an integer object includes the overhead of maintaining other object information along with its value. The additional information can include object type, reference count and other implementation-specific details.

If you store many integers and want to optimize the space spent, use the [`array` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html), specifically arrays constructed with `array.array('i')`.

Answer (score 5):

Integers in python are objects, and are therefore stored with extra overhead.

You can read more information about it [here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/)

The integer type in cpython is stored in a structure like so:

```
typedef struct {
  PyObject_HEAD
  long ob_ival;
} PyIntObject;
```

`PyObject_HEAD` is a macro that expands out into a *reference count* and a *pointer to the type object*.

So you can see that:

- `long ob_ival` - 4 bytes for a long.
- `Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt` - I would assume to size_t here is 4 bytes.
- `PyTypeObject *ob_type` - Is a pointer, so another 4 bytes.

12 bytes in total!