# Number of bytes required to store an integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I checked maximum size of the integer Python holds using `sys.maxsize` and it returned me `9223372036854775807`.

Then why I can still store a value greater than this range?

How many bytes are required to store an integer and do Python changes number of bytes depending on the size of an integer?

I am using Python 3.6

Comment: You do realize the number of bytes is not the same as the *value* that those bytes can represent?

Comment: In Python 2, any integer larger than `2^63 - 1` is a `long`, and will be represented with a trailing `L`: `9223372036854775808L`.

Comment: @ZachGates not really relevant to this question.

Comment: Fundamentally, `sys.maxsize` **is not the maximum size of an `int`**. It is the maximum size of a *machine word*, so, on your 64bit system, that is `2**63 - 1`. This many *bytes* is fundamentally how much memory can be allocated. Note, this is why, on 32-bit versions of Python, you cannot allocate more than 4 gigs of ram, no matter how much your hardware supports. This is because the maximum addressable size is `2**32 - 1 ==
4294967295`. It just *happens* that in Python 2, the `int` type uses a machine-word's size, but one *could* have used 128 bits...

Comment: you're mixing this up with `maxint`, the duplicate seems right

Comment: Python dynamically increases size of bytes based on the number to be stored in int. A good discussion about this is given in link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365624/sys-getsizeofint-returns-an-unreasonably-large-value

Answer (score 7):

If you check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) for `sys.maxsize`, you'll see

> `sys.maxsize`
>   An integer giving the maximum value a variable of type `Py_ssize_t` can take. It’s usually `2**31 - 1` on a 32-bit platform and `2**63 - 1` on a 64-bit platform.

There's nothing in there about Python `int`s! It's talking about `Py_ssize_t`, an internal C API thing with no practical relevance to working with Python `int`s.

Python `int`s use an arbitrary-precision representation that will use more bytes of memory to represent bigger integers. They are not limited by the values of `Py_ssize_t`s.

Comment: "Python ints use an arbitrary-precision representation that will use more bytes of memory to represent bigger integers. They are not limited by the values of Py_ssize_ts." - this is making sense. Thanks @user2357112

Comment: +1 and @vivek_ratnaparkhi  The text you quoted also clarify things for me too. I didn't use `Python2` much and I just wanted to know why `int` in `Python3` can hold integer larger than 64 bit unsigned integer e.g. in `C++`. Yes I just want someone tell me the fact: **"`int` is not a primitive type, it would use bytes larger than a `64 bit unsigned integer ` to represent a integer under the hood."**. Well, most answers of other posts are talking something else.  :-(