# Why ctypes.c_int larger than regular int()?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, ctypes

I've read the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365639/3701431) and `sys.getsizeof(int())` i.e. size of an instance produces

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(int())
24
```

Assuming `ctypes` should be lighter, I decided to try out same thing with `c_int()` instance, which to my surprise showed

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(ctypes.c_int())
136
```

So why is `c_int()` so large compared to regular `int()` instance ?