# sys.getsizeof(int) return 400 bytes

Tags: python

I intend to get the max size of int

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: sys.getsizeof(int)
Out[2]: 400
```

Does it mean that the maxint in python is 2**40

However, when I tried

```
In [5]: types = [int, float, complex, list, tuple, dict, set, True, False, None]
In [7]: [sys.getsizeof(type) for type in types]
Out[7]: [400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 28, 24, 16]
```

all the data types are 400 bytes.

What does it 400 bytes mean for integer?

Comment: Python's integers are bounded by your RAM only, so there's no "maxint".

Comment: You are seeing the size of the type class for each value in your list, not the max size of integers that can be represented in your interpretor. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365624/sys-getsizeofint-returns-an-unreasonably-large-value for further details.

Comment: but why `In [13]: sys.maxsize
Out[13]: 9223372036854775807` @ForceBru

Comment: @riderdragon, this is the maximum size lists, strings, dicts, and many other containers can have not the maximum supported integer number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code you're getting the size of the class not of an instance of the class.

Call int to get the size of an instance, like the following code

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(int())
24
```