# Different object size of True and False in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cpython, python-internals

Experimenting with magic methods (`__sizeof__` in particular) on different Python objects I stumbled over the following behaviour:

Python 2.7

```
>>> False.__sizeof__()
24
>>> True.__sizeof__()
24
```

Python 3.x

```
>>> False.__sizeof__()
24
>>> True.__sizeof__()
28
```

What changed in Python 3 that makes the size of `True` greater than the size of `False`?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365624/sys-getsizeofint-returns-an-unreasonably-large-value#comment77604598_10365639), the same behavior appears for `0` vs `1`

Comment: Note that assessing memory consumption using ``sys.getsizeof`` and ``__sizeof__`` (the later misses GC overhead) will lead to misleading results unless one really, really understands the Python interpreter. PyPy considers it an **error** to use any of these. For examples, integers 5 <= i <= 256 are singletons in CPython - ``[1, 1]`` and ``[1, 1, 1, 1]`` only differ by two additional pointers in size. In your case, you would have to find out whether ``True`` and ``1`` share the same memory for their value.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is because `bool` is a subclass of *`int`* in both Python 2 and 3.

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

But the *`int`* implementation has changed.

In Python 2, `int` was the one that was 32 or 64 bits, depending on the system, as opposed to arbitrary-length `long`.

In Python 3, `int` is arbitrary-length - the `long` of Python 2 was renamed to `int` and the original Python 2 `int` dropped altogether.

---

In Python 2 you get the exactly same behaviour for *long* objects `1L` and `0L`:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(1L)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(0L)
24
```

---

The `long`/Python 3 `int` is a variable-length object, just like a tuple - when it is allocated, enough memory is allocated to hold all the binary digits required to represent it. The length of the variable part is stored in the object head. `0` requires no binary digits (its variable length is 0), but even `1` spills over, and requires extra digits.

I.e. `0` is represented as binary string of length 0:

```
<>
```

and 1 is represented as a 30-bit binary string:

```
<000000000000000000000000000001>
```

The default configuration in Python uses [30 bits in a `uint32_t`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/598ceae876ff4a23072e59945597e945583de4ab/Include/longintrepr.h#L44); `so 2**30 - 1` still fits in 28 bytes on x86-64, and `2**30` will require 32;

`2**30 - 1` will be presented as

```
<111111111111111111111111111111>
```

i.e. all 30 value bits set to 1; 2**30 will need more, and it will have internal representation

```
<000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000>
```

---

As for `True` using **28** bytes instead of **24** - you need not worry. `True` is a **singleton** and therefore only 4 bytes are lost in *total* in any Python program, not 4 for every usage of `True`.

Comment: Yep, and long objects just use no extra pointer to represent 0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know bool was a subclass of int, but it totally makes sense now!

Answer (score 22):

Both `True` and `False` are [`longobject`s](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Objects/boolobject.c#L177) in CPython:

> ```
> struct _longobject _Py_FalseStruct = {
>     PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyBool_Type, 0)
>     { 0 }
> };
>
> struct _longobject _Py_TrueStruct = {
>     PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyBool_Type, 1)
>     { 1 }
> };
> ```

You thus can say that a Boolean is a subclass of a [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) `int` where `True` takes as value `1`, and `False` takes as value `0`. We thus make a call to [`PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/structures.html#c.PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT) with as `type` parameter a reference to `PyBool_Type` and with `ob_size` as value `0` and `1` respectively.

Now since [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), there is no `long` anymore: these have been merged, and the `int` object will, depending on the size of the number, take a different value.

If we inspect the source code of the [`longlobject` type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Include/longintrepr.h#L70), we see:

> ```
> /* Long integer representation.
>    The absolute value of a number is equal to
>         SUM(for i=0 through abs(ob_size)-1) ob_digit[i] * 2**(SHIFT*i)
>    Negative numbers are represented with ob_size < 0;
>    zero is represented by ob_size == 0.
>    In a normalized number, ob_digit[abs(ob_size)-1] (the most significant
>    digit) is never zero. Also, in all cases, for all valid i,
>         0 <= ob_digit[i] <= MASK.
>    The allocation function takes care of allocating extra memory
>    so that ob_digit[0] ... ob_digit[abs(ob_size)-1] are actually available.
>    CAUTION: Generic code manipulating subtypes of PyVarObject has to
>    aware that ints abuse ob_size's sign bit.
> */
>
> struct _longobject {
>     PyObject_VAR_HEAD
>     digit ob_digit[1];
> };
> ```

To make a long story short, an `_longobject` can be seen as an array of "digits", but you should here see digits not as decimal digits, but as groups of bits that thus can be added, multiplied, etc.

Now as is specified in the comment, it says that:

> ```
>    zero is represented by ob_size == 0.
> ```

So in case the value is zero, *no* digits are added, whereas for small integers (values less than 2<sup>30</sup> in CPython), it takes one digit, and so on.

In [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), there were two types of representations for numbers, `int`s (with a fixed size), you could see this as "one digit", and `long`s, with multiple digits. Since a `bool` was a subclass of `int`, both `True` and `False` occupied the same space.

Comment: Thanks for the good anwer! If SO would allow me to accept multiple answers I would have accepted yours as well! Guess the next step to become a better Python programmer will be to familiarize myself with the important bits of the CPython source...

Answer (score 6):

I haven't seen CPython code for this, but I believe this has something to do with optimization of integers in Python 3. Probably, as `long` was dropped, some optimizations were unified. `int` in Python 3 is arbitrary-sized int – the same as `long` was in Python 2. As `bool` stores in the same way as new `int`, it affects both.

Interesting part:

```
>>> (0).__sizeof__()
24

>>> (1).__sizeof__()  # Here one more "block" is allocated
28

>>> (2**30-1).__sizeof__()  # This is the maximum integer size fitting into 28
28
```

+ bytes for object headers should complete the equation.

Comment: Actually, now in Python 3, `int` is just what Python 2 `long` was, it was really `int` that was "dropped"

Comment: Internally – absolutely true, I'm talking about names, but thx for clarification

Comment: Indeed, in CPython 3 source code, it's still longobject

Comment: It is actually deoptimization... pessimization?

Comment: It's probably not. I may be wrong, but this overhead does not cost as much as two different types + seamless cast in runtime. The truth is, you rarely operate such a huge amount of ints in normal python program to care about this extra memory. If you do – you should use something like numpy to run with ~0 overhead and have pure int32/64 – no headers, no reallocation. But overflows from time to time )

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [cpython code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/260ec2c36abd73bac51489108409160427979ede/Objects/boolobject.c#L177) for `True` and `False`

Internally it is represented as integer

```
PyTypeObject PyBool_Type = {
        PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
        "bool",
        sizeof(struct _longobject),
        0,
        0,                                          /* tp_dealloc */
        0,                                          /* tp_print */
        0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
        0,                                          /* tp_setattr */
        0,                                          /* tp_reserved */
        bool_repr,                                  /* tp_repr */
        &bool_as_number,                            /* tp_as_number */
        0,                                          /* tp_as_sequence */
        0,                                          /* tp_as_mapping */
        0,                                          /* tp_hash */
        0,                                          /* tp_call */
        bool_repr,                                  /* tp_str */
        0,                                          /* tp_getattro */
        0,                                          /* tp_setattro */
        0,                                          /* tp_as_buffer */
        Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,                         /* tp_flags */
        bool_doc,                                   /* tp_doc */
        0,                                          /* tp_traverse */
        0,                                          /* tp_clear */
        0,                                          /* tp_richcompare */
        0,                                          /* tp_weaklistoffset */
        0,                                          /* tp_iter */
        0,                                          /* tp_iternext */
        0,                                          /* tp_methods */
        0,                                          /* tp_members */
        0,                                          /* tp_getset */
        &PyLong_Type,                               /* tp_base */
        0,                                          /* tp_dict */
        0,                                          /* tp_descr_get */
        0,                                          /* tp_descr_set */
        0,                                          /* tp_dictoffset */
        0,                                          /* tp_init */
        0,                                          /* tp_alloc */
        bool_new,                                   /* tp_new */
    };

    /* The objects representing bool values False and True */

    struct _longobject _Py_FalseStruct = {
        PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyBool_Type, 0)
        { 0 }
    };

    struct _longobject _Py_TrueStruct = {
        PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyBool_Type, 1)
    { 1 }
```

Comment: I think i just was not as quick to answer properly as others :)

Comment: The answer only gets halfway there. It's represented as an integer.. yeah? And so what?

Comment: @wim I don't see the need to explain it further since guys above already did great job at this. I don't want to duplicate content. Please refer to their answers.

Comment: agree, it's not good to duplicate content in others answers (in these cases, usually best just to self-delete answer). Was just attempting to explain why it may have been downvoted.

Comment: @wim Downvotes appeared when i posted first version of the answer, someone probably disliked it. Since my answer is incomplete and i don't want duplicating the better answers should I delete mine?

Comment: I think so, but it's up to you. Should you wait for it to maybe get +3 and then delete you may earn a [disciplined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge... :)