# the instance of int has much less bytes than its inherited class

Tags: python

When I tried the sys.getsizeof:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(int)
400
>>> sys.getsizeof(2)
28
```

I am puzzled about the result:

2 is an instance of class int but have much less bytes than its inherited class.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(list)
400
>>> sys.getsizeof(list("list"))
120
```

The same is list.

Does 2 not inherit from class int?

Comment: @Ayxan nope, because that was wrong af. I don't know why it does that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["sys.getsizeof(int)" returns an unreasonably large value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365624/sys-getsizeofint-returns-an-unreasonably-large-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is a class, that means it is a `type` object:

```
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> getsizeof(int)
400
```

[sys.getsizeof](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) returns the size of **that object**, not its instance. Use `()` to create an instance of `int` and see its size

```
>>> getsizeof(int())
24
>>> getsizeof(int(2))
28

>>> getsizeof(0)
24
>>> getsizeof(2)
28
```

This doesn't just apply to the built-in types, same behavior can be observed using user-defined classes:

```
>>> class a:
...     pass
... 
>>> getsizeof(a)
1056
>>> getsizeof(a())
56
>>> obj = a()
>>> getsizeof(obj)
56
```