# Use of Inf on Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am currently translating a MATLAB program into Python. I successfully ported all the previous  vector operations using numpy. However I am stuck in the following  bit of code which is a cosine similarity measure.

```
% W and ind are different sized matrices
dist = full(W * (W(ind2(range),:)' - W(ind1(range),:)' +  W(ind3(range),:)')); 
for i=1:length(range)
    dist(ind1(range(i)),i) = -Inf;
    dist(ind2(range(i)),i) = -Inf;
    dist(ind3(range(i)),i) = -Inf;
end
disp(dist)
[~, mx(range)] = max(dist);
```

I did not understand  the following part.

```
dist(indx(range(i)),i) = -Inf;
```

What actuality is happening when you use

```
= -Inf;
```

on the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just assigns a [minus infinity](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inf.html) value to the left-hand side.

It may appear weird to assign that value, particularly because a distance [cannot be negative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition). But it looks like it's used for effectively removing those entries from the `max` computation in the last line.

If Python doesn't have "infinity" (I don't know Python) *and* if `dist` is really a distance (hence *nonnegative*) , you could use any negative value instead of `-inf` to achieve the same effect, namely remove those entries from the `max` computation.

Comment: Yes, the result of `dist(indx(range(i)),i)` is Inf.

Answer (score 4):

In Matlab (see: [Inf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inf.html)):

> Inf returns the IEEE® arithmetic representation for positive infinity.

So `Inf` produces a value that is greater than all other numeric values. `-Inf` produces a value that is guaranteed to be less than any other numeric value. It's generally used when you want to iteratively find a maximum and need a first value to compare to that's always going to be less than your first comparison.

According to Wikipedia (see: [IEEE 754 Inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity)):

> Positive and negative infinity are represented thus:
>
> sign = 0 for positive infinity, 1 for negative infinity.
>   biased exponent = all 1 bits.
>   fraction = all 0 bits.

Python has the same concept using `'-inf'` (see Note 6 [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)):

> float also accepts the strings “nan” and “inf” with an optional prefix “+” or “-” for Not a Number (NaN) and positive or negative infinity.

```
>>> a=float('-inf')
>>> a
-inf
>>> b=-27983.444
>>> min(a,b)
-inf
```

Answer (score 2):

The -Inf is typically used to initialize a variable such that you later can use it to in a comparison in a loop. 
For instance if I want to find the the maximum value in a function (and have forgotten the command max). Then I would have made something like:

```
function maxF = findMax(f,a,b)
maxF = -Inf;
x = a:0.001:b;
for i = 1:length(x)
    if f(x) > maxF
         maxF = f(x);
    end
end
```

It is a method in matlab to make sure that any other value is larger than the current. So the comparison in Python would be -sys.maxint +1.

See for instance:
[Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)