# sys.maxint returns a value corresponding to a 32 bit system even though I am using a 64 bit

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I am not very knowledgeable about system architecture, and have just started learning Python.

In one of the tutorial videos it was mentioned that running sys.maxint in the interpreter will return the biggest integer that is available to you.

It was also mentioned that 2147483647 is the integer that corresponds to a 32 bit system. That's is the integer that I am being returned when I run sys.maxint.

I am using Enthought Canopy (64 bit) on a 64 bit OS. Windows 8, to be precise.

Is there any way I can increase the sys.maxint value to one that corresponds a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Did you download and compile 32 bit version of Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Comment: Though, as @thavan points out, it is possible (probable) you're using a 32bit python. Also, the bit-width of the system has nothing to do with the maximum value of a number. It's perfectly possible to represent a 64bit number on an 8-bit computer, it just wouldn't likely be very efficient as it probably would lack the ability to do 64bit operations in a single cycle. The bit-width of a system only has a hard constraint on the maximum size of a pointer in memory, and thus the maximum amount of memory addressable.

Comment: @thavan, I just downloaded Enthought Canopy. All I know is that they use Python 2.7. I never had to explicitly compile python.

Comment: Use [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) instead. The value will depend on whether you're running 32- or 64-bit Python.

Comment: [See also this related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os)

Comment: @martineau, I tried that too. But it returns the integer as a long (9223372036854775807L). I hear Long integers take more time during computations than regular ints. Which is why I was hoping to utilize the 64 bit version ints.

Comment: Also, when I run platform.architecture() it returns ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

Comment: Enthought Canopy has both 32 and 64 bit builds.  You probably downloaded the 32 bit build is all.

Comment: @tom10, That isn't the issue. I checked that the Enthought Canopy build is 64 bit.

Comment: I think it's WIndows (its C/C++ compiler, at least) forcing `sys.maxint` to `2**31 - 1` even on 64-bit Python builds.  If you're stuck on Windows, I don't think you have a way out (maybe you could possibly switch to a **real** OS...?-).

Comment: @AlexMartelli, help a noob out. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @DhruvDharamshi, I'd personally suggest Ubuntu Linux instead of Windows, but most Linux or BSD versions (including Mac OS X, a great BSD variant) would be fine too.  If you're stuck on Windows due to other constraints, I dunno - I guess there may be better C/C++ compilers (and Python versions built on them), but I don't know which ones (dropped Windows forever about 12 years ago, after wasting a LOT of my life on it -- see http://www.aleax.it/TutWin32/ -- and my life became SO much better I have a hard time believing it, myself...!-).

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
>>> ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
>>> 2147483647
>>> sys.maxint+1
>>> 2147483648L
```

Seems to be a limitation on Windows.

I would not worry about it, as Python supports bignums and won't overflow. Although performance will be lower if you exceed `sys.maxint`.