# Python displaying ints as long?

Tags: python, python-2.7, long-integer

So here are two functions for finding the prime factors of a number. 
Credits: Triptych
https://stackoverflow.com/a/412942/6211963

```
def prime_factors1(n):
    """Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"""
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
        d = d + 1

    return factors

def prime_factors2(n):
    """Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"""
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
        d = d + 1
        if d*d > n:
            if n > 1: factors.append(n)
            break
    return factors
```

Obviously the second code runs a lot faster, but why does it output the largest factor as long-type rather than int?

```
>>> prime_factors1(65126264424)
[2, 2, 2, 3, 13, 29, 7197863]

>>> prime_factors2(65126264424)
[2, 2, 2, 3, 13, 29, 7197863L]
```

Comment: In the second version, you're appending `n`, which is a long.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Python 2.7.11 on Linux x86_64.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with Python 2.7.11 on Linux x86_64 too

Comment: This is what I'm using: Jupyter QtConsole 4.2.0. Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| IPython 4.1.2

Comment: What OS? Win, OS X, Linux, ....?

Comment: On Windows 10 64-bit: `65126264424 > sys.maxint` returns True, on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit it returns False.

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28911129/2285236

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the following. In `prime_factors1(n)`, the last factor is appended here:

```
while n > 1:
    while n % d == 0:
        factors.append(d)
```

where `d` starts out at `2` (definitely an `int` no matter which runtime), grows via `d = d + 1` (addition of two `int`) and - when it is appended as a factor - stands at `7197863` (still an `int`).

In `prime_factors2(65126264424)`, however, you append the last factor here:

```
if d*d > n:
    if n > 1: factors.append(n)
```

where `n` starts out at `65126264424` and shrinks via `n /= d`. This will not change the type of `n` if it starts out as a `long` (if `n` is a `long` and `d` is an `int`, the result will still be a `long` no matter how small). The question therefore becomes: **Is `65126264424` a `long`?**

The answer depends on your python runtime:

1. In a 32-bit runtime, you typically have 32-bit integers that max out at `(2**31 - 1)` or `2147483647` which is smaller than `65126264424`.
2. In a 64-bit runtime, you typically have 64-bit integers that max out at `(2**63 - 1)` or `9223372036854775807` which is bigger than `65126264424`.

See the output of `sys.maxint` and it should be smaller than `65126264424`.