# smallest negative int in Python

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7.x Stack. And using sys.maxint for positive max integer (if it is wrong usage, please feel free to correct me). Sometimes I also need to initialize an integer to be smallest negative integer value. Wondering what is the most elegant/correct way in Python 2.7.x Stack?

Thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Watch out - `sys.maxint + 1` will work just fine, without overflow. Python will just hand you a `long`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-sys.maxint - 1
```

Negative limits are always one off from positive limits, due to how integers are represented in binary.

Comment: thanks. Why need -1?

Comment: Note however that Python does not have a limit for integer values.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints .

Comment: The `-1` is because in the usual [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation, zero is positive,so there is space for one extra negative number. Eg signed bytes range from -128 to 127.

Comment: @jjmontes: This is... misleading, depending on how you interpret "integer". At least in Python 2, it does not have a limit for integral values, but it does have a limit for `int` (after `maxint`, they are `long`).

Answer (score 16):

For comparisons (like to find out smallest value, etc) I normally use `float('-inf')` , this is not an int, but is smaller than any int, and can be used for commparison with ints. Example -

```
>>> float('-inf')
-inf

>>> -sys.maxint -1 > float('-inf')
True
```

Comment: Oh! Awesome, I'll never use a dodgy random initial value for comparisons anymore. Thanks!