# What does importing maxint do? python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

In an algorithms course we're using python 2.7 because we "hand in" our code on the course website and automatically test it with different input, and I suppose it's a compatibility issue.

The current assignment is a all-to-all shortest path problem, and we're given a framework for our code in which they import maxint. Just wondering what maxint does.

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint)

Comment: It's right in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.maxint)

Comment: [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7604966/2301450)

Answer (score 0):

[Python Standard Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex). An excerpt below, emphasis mine.

> There are four distinct numeric types: plain integers, long integers, floating point numbers, and complex numbers. In addition, Booleans are a subtype of plain integers. Plain integers (also just called integers) are implemented using long in C, which gives them at least 32 bits of precision **(sys.maxint is always set to the maximum plain integer value for the current platform, the minimum value is -sys.maxint - 1)**.

The only reason I can think of for them to be importing it, is for bounds checking reasons.