# Python - changing Pandas DataFrame with float64's to list with integers

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, type-conversion

I have a Pandas DataFrame on which I would like to do some manipulations. First I sort my dataframe on the entropy using this code:

```
entropy_dataframe.sort_values(by='entropy',inplace=True,ascending=False)
```

This gives me the following dataframe (`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`):

```
      entropy    identifier
486  1.000000  3.955030e+09
584  1.000000  8.526030e+09
397  1.000000  5.623020e+09
819  0.999700  1.678030e+09
..        ...           ...
179  0.000000  3.724020e+09
766  0.000000  6.163020e+09
770  0.000000  6.163020e+09
462  0.000000  7.005020e+09
135  0.000000  3.069001e+09
```

Now I would like to select the 10 largest identifiers and return a list with the corresponding 10 identifiers (as integers). I have tried selecting the top 10 identifiers by either using:

```
entropy_top10 = entropy_dataframe.head(10)['identifier']
```

And:

```
entropy_top10 = entropy_dataframe[:10]
entropy_top10 = entropy_top10['identifier']
```

Which both give the following result (`<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`):

```
397    2.623020e+09
823    8.678030e+09
584    2.526030e+09
486    7.955030e+09
396    2.623020e+09
555    9.768020e+09
492    7.955030e+09
850    9.606020e+09
159    2.785020e+09
745    4.609030e+09
Name: identifier, dtype: float64
```

Even though both work, the pain starts after this operation as I now would like to change this Pandas Series with dtype float64 to a list of integers.

I have tried the following:

```
entropy_top10= np.array(entropy_top10,dtype=pd.Series)
entropy_top10= entropy_top10.astype(np.int64)
entropy_top10= entropy_top10.tolist()
```

Which results in (`<type 'list'>`):

```
[7955032207L, 8613030044L, 2623057011L, 2526030291L, 7951030016L, 2623020357L, 9768028572L, 9606023013L, 2785021210L, 9768023351L]
```

Which is a list of longs (while I'm looking for integers).

Anyone that can help me out here? Thanks in advance!

--- EDIT ---

The problem lies 'here'. When I remove `entropy_top10= entropy_top10.tolist()`, it results in a `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` with elements of dtype `numpy.int64`. When I add the code again, I get a `<type 'list'>` with elements `long`.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Are you sure, that regular integers would be large enough to hold the values? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints -- in 32bit python, the maximum integer value should be 2147483647

Comment: If I do `sys.maxint` I get 2147483647. I'm fairly sure that all identifiers have a maximum of 10 characters. 

If I try `python -V` in my command line it gives me Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit).

Comment: According to your `sys.maxint`, you run 32bit python. And even if numbers in your list have a maximum length of 10 digits, they may be larger than your `maxint`. Already the first value in your list `7955032207` does not fit into a 32bit integer. Thus, you will have to use `long`, as python already did.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. One remark though. In another part of my code I also have a list consisting of values which have numpy's `int64` datatype. In this specific list Python is able to store these identifiers (also values larger than the `sys.maxint`) as `integer` instead of `long`. Any idea why it is possible there?

Comment: In fact, when I remove `entropy_top10= entropy_top10.tolist()` from the method in my original question I get an `numpy.ndarray` which does contain elements from the datatype `numpy.int64`. Hence, when performing transforming this `numpy.ndarray` into a `list`, the elements are also transformed from an `numpy.int64` to a `long`. Is it still clear or should I adjust my original question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since users may not skim through all of the comments on your original question, I'll condense our results into a single answer.

- According to `sys.maxint`, a 32bit version of python is running. Since some list elements are larger than `maxint` (`2**31 - 1`), the elements are stored as `long` values
- The transformation `entropy_top10.astype(np.int64)` creates a `numpy.ndarray` of 64bit integers in `numpy`'s own data type. `numpy` ships a 64bit integer data type even for 32bit python (which is no python native type whatsoever!).
- The transformation `entropy_top10.tolist()` converts the `numpy` data type back to python's native data type. Since you are running 32bit, the `int64` can only be convertet to `long` type
- For a 64bit python version, the `tolist()` transformation would most likely result in python native integer types, because the values would fit into the regular integer at 64bit (`2**63 - 1`)

The reason for your list containing `long` items is the translation between `numpy` datatypes and native datatypes of your installed `python` version. Independent from the actual python version that is used to run code, `numpy` is consistent in its own datatypes.

### Edit

To make the difference between the list's type and the items' types clearer, see this code example:

```
a = np.array([3123123123, 1512451234], dtype=np.int64)
print('ALL NUMPY')
print('  List items', a)
print('  List type', type(a))
print('  Item type', type(a[0]))

l = a.tolist()
print('ALL PYTHON NATIVE')
print('  List items', l)
print('  List type', type(l))
print('  Item type', type(l[0]))

c = [i for i in a]
print('NATIVE LIST, NUMPY TYPE')
print('  List items', c)
print('  List type', type(c))
print('  Item type', type(c[0]))
```

It gives the following output:

```
ALL NUMPY
  List items [3123123123 1512451234]
  List type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
  Item type <type 'numpy.int64'>
ALL PYTHON NATIVE
  List items [3123123123L, 1512451234L]
  List type <type 'list'>
  Item type <type 'long'>
NATIVE LIST, NUMPY TYPE
  List items [3123123123, 1512451234]
  List type <type 'list'>
  Item type <type 'numpy.int64'>
```

From this output, we can learn, that `numpy`'s `tolist()` function does not only convert the list from `numpy.ndarray` to `list` but also transforms all items' types from `numpy.int64` to `long`. Manually transforming the array into a native list (using a comprehension here) yields a python native list with elements of type `numpy.int64`.

Comment: In some other parts of my code I was able to produce lists with integers from the same identifiers. See for example the following:
`[3368030009, 6191090062, 8486030004, 7859030003, 4562030005, 8343090057, 2959090000, 7155090021, 9615030065, 6513030004]`
Type of object: `<type 'list'>`
Type of elements of list: `<type 'numpy.int64'>`

Comment: The difference is that the elements of your list are `numpy.int64`, which is the `type` for 64bit integers that `numpy` ships. These are no *native python* integers, since 32bit python **does not have** 64 bit integers.