# What is the largest value Python 3's int can hold?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overflow

I read that `sys.maxsize` is the largest value Python 3's int can hold.
However, it seems not to be the case; I can put much bigger number and it still does not overflow.

What is the limit that `int` can hold in Python 3? I am asking because I am converting a string to an integer and I am wondering if I need to worry about a possibility of overflow when doing the conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Comment: [*"there is no longer a limit to the value of integers"*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26121781/3001761)

Comment: Depends on how much memory is available to the Python interpreter on your systems (they can be any size that free memory allows).

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs what's new page](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> The sys.maxint constant was removed, since there is no longer a limit
>   to the value of integers. However, sys.maxsize can be used as an
>   integer larger than any practical list or string index. It conforms to
>   the implementation’s “natural” integer size and is typically the same
>   as sys.maxint in previous releases on the same platform (assuming the
>   same build options).