# Why numpy converts 20000001 int to float32 as 20000000.?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to put some numbers into numpy array

```
>>> np.array([20000001]).astype('float32')
array([ 20000000.], dtype=float32)
```

where did 1 go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply don't have enough precision.  The `float32` has only *approximately* 7 digits of accuracy, whereas the `float64` has approximately 16 digits of accuracy.  Thus, any time you convert to a `float32`, it's only guaranteed to be "correct" to within about a part in 10^7.  So, for example, you can try this:

```
>>> np.array([20000001]).astype('float64')
array([ 20000001.])
```

That's the expected answer.  (The `dtype=float64` is automatically omitted, because that's the default.)  In fact, you can go further and find

```
>>> np.array([2000000000000001]).astype('float64')[0]
2000000000000001.0
```

but

```
>>> np.array([20000000000000001]).astype('float64')[0]
20000000000000000.0
```

At some point, no matter how high your precision, you'll always get to the point where `float`s drop the least significant digits.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for more info on `float`s.

On the other hand, python's `int` objects have many more digits they can keep track of.  In python 3, it's practically unlimited.  So `int`s have basically infinite precision.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604981/1194883) for more info on `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

with `float32` you can't resolve it

```
>>> np.finfo(np.float32).eps
1.1920929e-07
```

`eps` here gives you "the smallest representable positive number such that 1 + `eps` != 1" which is a measure for `float32` accuracy. Multiply that with 20,000,000 and it's just too large.

Less informally, if one wants to avoid computing the binary representation of n then eps * n / base is a convenient lower bound for the resolution around n. While as @hobbs points out eps * n is an upper bound.

Also note that for example 1 + 0.6*eps may actually return something != 1, this is, however, due to rounding. Subtracting 1 from the result returns eps, not 0.6*eps.

Comment: That's not exactly the right way to compute that... although it is within a factor of 2 of the correct value. The actual precision of a 32-bit float in the vicinity of 20,000,000 is exactly 2 (as it is for any value between 2^24 + 1 and 2^25).

Comment: @hobbs well, unless I'm completely mistaken eps x n / base does give you a lower bound for the smallest number you can add to n such that etc.

Comment: upper, rather. The precision at 1.99 is the same as it is at 1, not 1.99 times worse; it jumps at 2.

Comment: @hobbs and what use would an upper bound be here, hm? It is very simple: A lower bound for some y is a number that is guaranteed not to exceed y. If we want to show that 1 can't be effectively added to 20,000,000 we need to show that r > 1 where r is the rersolution at 20,000,000 if we have a lower bound b for r and b > 1 then we can conclude r > 1 because r >= b > 1. with an upper bound this does not work.

Comment: I don't disagree that an upper bound is not very useful; my point is that the value you provided *is* an upper bound, not a lower bound.

Comment: (Luckiliy, the lower bound is simply half that.)

Comment: @hobbs just to be sure you did see the 1 / base there? Or are we disagreeing on rounding? Something like 20,000,000 + 1.1 = 20,000,002? I'd say that doesn't count since you haven't added 1.1 you've added 2. If you check `np.float32(1) + np.float32(eps*0.6)` you'll also get something which is not 1, so the library agrees with me on that.

Comment: I missed the `/base`. Apologies.

Comment: @hobbs no prob, sorry for getting tetchy so easily. I'll clarify the post.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `float64` works in this case:

```
>>> np.array([20000001]).astype('float32')
array([ 20000000.], dtype=float32)
>>> np.array([20000001]).astype('float64')
array([ 20000001.])
```

**How does a `float` work under the hood:**

[image]

**What's the difference between `float32` and `float64`?:**

- 32bit (single precision float): 24 bit significand
- 64bit (double precision float): 53 bit significand

With `float32`, you get 23 bits to represent the digits plus 1 bit to represent the sign. Lets view `20000001` in binary:

```
0b 1 0011 0001 0010 1101 0000 0001  ---->
0b 1 0011 0001 0010 1101 0000 00
```

So the last two bits "01" will get cut off when converting from `int` to `float32`.

Interestingly, converting `20000003` will get you `20000004`:

```
>>> np.array([20000003]).astype('float32')
array([ 20000004.], dtype=float32)
```

And that is:

```
0b 1 0011 0001 0010 1101 0000 0011  ---->
0b 1 0011 0001 0010 1101 0000 01
```

Comment: Very nice explanation. Please allow me to point out a small inaccuracy. Even though there are 23 bits for the significand the actual precision is 24bits because of the implicit leading 1 which needn't be stored. You can check this with `np.float32(20_000_002)` which is represented  exactly.