# How to fix "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'" in PY4E

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im doing py4e assignment 5.2. In the browser when im typing my code everything works, however when I try using CMD, code doesn't work giving error:"TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'"

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    sval = input("enter a number ")
    if sval=="done":
        break
    try:
        fval = int(sval)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if fval > largest:
        largest = fval
    elif smallest is None:
        smallest = fval
    elif fval < smallest :
        smallest = fval


print("Maximum is",largest)
print("Minimum is ",smallest)
```

```
it is giving error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw_ch_5_2.py", line 12, in <module>
    if fval > largest:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: `largest` is `None`, and as the error says you can't compare None to an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JaredSmith said in their comment, you set `largest` to `None` which is `NoneType`. You can set `largest` to something really small at the beginning (some large negative) and `smallest` to something really big.

As an example, instead of setting to `None`, you can do:

```
largest = -10000000000
smallest = 10000000000
```

You'll also need to change your code slightly

```
if fval > largest:
    largest = fval
if fval < smallest:
    smallest = fval
```

This is a way to do it when you know the range of the number will be between -10000000000 and 10000000000.

Comment: You could also assign the values of `-sys.maxsize - 1` and `sys.maxsize` to `largest` and `smallest` respectively, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544543/2605758).

Comment: thank you, it works. However what should we do if we want the largest or smallest be close to infinity? Because user can input number bigger than 10000000000 or something like this

Answer (score 1):

Another way to ensure that you don't compare an `int` to `None` (which causes your `TypeError`) is to check whether the value of `largest` or `smallest` is `None` *before* you do any other comparisons.

```
if largest is None or fval > largest:
    largest = fval
if smallest is None or fval < smallest:
    smallest = fval
```

This is a boolean logic function known as [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2580136/2605758). In simple terms, because the first part of the expression (`largest is None`) returns `True` if the vairable you're checking is `None`, the interpreter doesn't bother trying to evaluate the second part of the expression (`fval > largest` or `fval < smallest`), because the whole expression evaluates to `True`.