# Longest Python variable value

Tags: python

I was working with python and I tried to see what is the largest number a variable in python can hold. Interestingly, I found that I kept on increasing that number and there was no end limit. Is there any max number limit in Python? My code is

```
import sys
a = sys.maxsize
for i in range(200):
   a *=sys.maxsize
print(a)
```

and the answer was a 10,12 lines integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Comment: Yes Thanks for suggest

Answer (score 0):

Integers in Python can be arbitrarly large. There are lots on articles about how that is handled internally, like https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/how-python-implements-super-long-integers-12icwon5vk.