# Python: Bit Array to Integer: Randomly getting negative integers with NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
>>> np.version.version
'1.17.2'
```

I am maintaining integers as a bit array in order to manipulate at bit level algorithmically. I am using a fairly standard way to convert from the bit array to an integer and then view in decimal format.

```
def decimal(binaryValue):
    decimalValue = 0
    for bit in binaryValue:
        decimalValue = (decimalValue << 1) | bit
        print(decimalValue) #For testing
    return decimalValue
```

I was weirdly receiving negative integers randomly for certain arrays 64-bit or larger. I realised after some hair pulling and crazy debugging that this happens when I use a NumPy array. No issue with regular lists. Here is a specific example:

```
>>> b = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
>>> decimal(b)
1
3
7
...
4418570559336253839
8837141118672507678
17674282237345015357
17674282237345015357
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b_np = np.array(b)
>>> b_np
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
>>> decimal(b_np)
1
3
7
...
4418570559336253839
8837141118672507678
-772461836364536259
-772461836364536259
>>> np.binary_repr(decimal(b))
'1111010101000111101010100000110101110000111100100010011000111101'
>>> np.binary_repr(decimal(b_np))
'-101010111000010101011111001010001111000011011101100111000011'
```

As you can see, with the numpy array representation, something happens on the last bit evaluation. If I convert the numpy array back to a list, then I now get a negative number! Very very weird. Something happens in the numpy space. But c is identical to b.

```
>>> c = list(b_np)
>>> c
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
>>> decimal(c)
1
3
7
...
4418570559336253839
8837141118672507678
-772461836364536259
-772461836364536259
>>>np_binary_rep(decimal(c))
'-101010111000010101011111001010001111000011011101100111000011'
```

Simple checks:

```
>>> len(b)
64
>>> len(b_np)
64
>>> len(c)
64
>>> b == c
True
>>> b == b_np
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
```

What is going on? Obviously a 64-bit issue, but can't see where. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to transform your `b` variable, your are assigning `int` data type to the `decimal` variable, but when you do it with a `numpy.array` datatype like `b_np`, you are assigning `numpy.int64` datatype.

## `int` type

The int type can represent an integer up to `sys.maxsize * 2 + 1`:

```py
import sys
print(sys.maxsize * 2 + 1)
# Prints 18446744073709551615 (length 20)
```

This means that your first result `17674282237345015357` is representable by an unsigned int because `18446744073709551615 > 17674282237345015357 == True`.

## `numpy.int64 type`

This datatype can represent integers between `-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807`, you can check [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html).
Since `9223372036854775807` (length 19) is smaller than your expected result `18446744073709551615` the 64th byte is taken as a sign, that's why only your last result gives a negative value. If you try the same example with an array with '62`length (`2**62` representable values), you would see that you won't have negative values.

Comment: Python 3 `int` type allow calculations with arbitrary long numbers, so there is no need to check that it's `< sys.maxsize * 2 + 1`, but `numpy.int64` indeed has limitations.

Comment: Absolutely, but that calculation is the max word size, this post has a really interesting answer about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints

Comment: [replacing previous comment] Thanks! I knew it was to do with a 64-bit limit, but couldn't at all see where. Since I set `decimalValue = 0`, which is of type Python 3 `int`, I didn't see the issue. Completely missed that `int | numpy.int64` is of type `numpy.int64`. I would have expected instead that the right operand be upcasted to `int'. I have switched my array to a standard Python list. It creates some inefficiencies downstream, but need > 64-bit precision for this purpose.