# What is the maximum limit of a simple counter in a While loop - Python

Tags: python, while-loop

What will be the maximum counting integer in an infinite While loop

```
count = 0
while True:
    c += 1
    print(c)
```

Is it `int.maxsize()` for Python3?

Comment: Python is fine with arbitrary length integers. So, the limiting factor is your memory.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604981/9050514

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with the `sys` module of the standard library.

Max `int` size;

```
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
```

Min `int` size;

```
>>> -sys.maxint - 1
-9223372036854775808
```