# What is the max number for a Python variable?

Tags: python, variables

In most compiled languages, the max value for an integer was around 2.147 billion. In Javascript, it is around 10^308. But what is it in Python? If, in the Javascript console, you ask 10 to the power of 309, it return `Infinity`. But, if you do that in the python shell, it returns a one with 309 zeros. I tried 10^500, 10^500, 10^1000, and even 10^10000 in the shell, and all of them returned a one with the respective number of zeroes. For the last one, I had to confirm the printing of the number, as it made the shell a tad bit slower. 

So, do you know what the max value for a Python variable Is?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Python had handle any size integer.

Comment: `import math ... math.factorial(10000)` should tell you all you really need to know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses a big number integer library in its implementation of an integer type.

This means the number is arbitrarily large.

Eventually you'll hit a limit such as memory. sys.int_info gives you information on the integer, including the largest it can be.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check the maximum value

```
import sys
print("Float value information: ",sys.float_info)
print("\nInteger value information: ",sys.int_info)
print("\nMaximum size of an integer: ",sys.maxsize)
```