# Initializing a variable with INT_MIN in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

**About the code**
The maximum sum subarray problem is the task of finding a contiguous subarray with the largest sum, within a given one-dimensional array A[1...n] of numbers.
Read more: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

**Pseudo Code**

```
for(each element in array):
    max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
    if(max_ending_here < a[i])
        max_ending_here = a[i]

    if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
        max_so_far = max_ending_here

    return max_so_far
```

**My problem**
This algo is little modified to work for negative integer and that modification is that the  `max_so_far` variable should be initialized with INT_MIN but i cannot find a way to do so in Python

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/

Comment: [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints) might help.

Comment: @shubhamprashar My output on Python 3.8: `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'maxint'`

Comment: it should be `sys.maxsize`

Comment: also, I just found min int be returned by `-sys.maxsize - 1` is it correct?

Comment: I usually use `float('-inf')` for this.

Answer (score 0):

we can write INT_MIN by importing sys
import sys
MIN_INT = -sys.maxsize - 1

Comment: No, this is not correct. You can happily make a smaller integer in Python, try just `print(-sys.maxsize - 2)` python integers are arbitrarily sized.