# Integers in python are supposed to be unlimited but I'm getting OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Tags: python, integer, overflow

I'm having an overflow issue, but I'm not sure why since integers are supposed to be unlimited in pytho.
The issue is happening at the last line.
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large').

```
temperature_planet = 200
temperature_atmosphere = 250

epsilon = 0.25
dt = 60*10
heat_capacity = 1E5
insolation = 1370
sigma = 5.67E-8
planet_radius = 6.4E6
while True:
        temperature_planet += dt*(circle*insolation + sphere* epsilon*sigma* temperature_atmosphere**4 - sphere*sigma*temperature_planet**4)/heat_capacity
```

If I tried initializing temperature_planet with decimal.Decimal I get:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with various floats... `epsilon`, `heat_capacity`, `sigma`, and `planet_radius`....

Your expression,

```
dt*(circle*insolation + sphere* epsilon*sigma* temperature_atmosphere**4 - sphere*sigma*temperature_planet**4)/heat_capacity
```

will always be a float. Why do you expect otherwise?

Comment: Is there a way to make my float unbounded?, I tried doing decimal.Decimal(200) when initializing temperature_planet. the issue with that was I couldn't run the function * on a decimal for some reason

Comment: @user3718247 no, `float` objects will **always** be fixed length. You can work with `decimal.Decimal` objects, but they aren't infinite length, just arbitrarily large (and you have to decide on the size beforehand, I believe). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to save the result for the equation in a variable so I can display it on a scatter chart

Comment: @user3718247 you absolutely can multiply `decimal.Decimal` objects with `*`. If you are actually encountering an error, you should post that error. "For some reason" isn't helpful

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'

Comment: @user3718247 **because you keep using `float` objects**

Comment: @user3718247 but don't post the error in a comment, edit your original question with what you are doing and the exact error. Always post the full error message including the stack trace

Comment: I just initialize all the constants as decimal.Decimal(). That worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are compiling with python2 instead of with python3.

Check this other question: [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Comment: The loop is running forever

Comment: The python version running on my system is 3.7.6

Comment: Even in Python 2, `int` objects will automatically convert to `long`, which are unlimited. But that isn't the problem.