# Maximum/minimum value returned by Python's hash() function

Tags: python, hash, hashtable

Context: building a consistent hashing algorithm.

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) for Python's `hash()` function states:

> Return the hash value of the object (if it has one). Hash values are integers.

However, it does not explicitly state whether the function maps to an integer range (with a minimum and a maximum) or not.

Coming from other languages where values for primitive types are bounded (e.g. C#'s/Java's `Int.MaxValue`), I know that [Python's likes to think in "unbounded" terms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604998/3873799) – i.e. switching from `int` to `long` in the background.

Am I to assume that the `hash()` function also is unbounded? Or is it bounded, for example mapping to what Python assigns to the [max/min values of the "int-proper"](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/ints/#:%7E:text=These%20represent%20numbers%20in%20the,size%2C%20but%20not%20smaller.) – i.e. between `-2147483648` through `2147483647`?

Comment: You've read the note at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__?

Comment: " switching from int to long in the background." that distinction doesn't exist anymore in Python 3, it's `int` across the entire range and the switch from "short int" to "long int" to "infinite" is not exposed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others pointed out, there is a misplaced<sup>[1]</sup> Note in the documentation that reads:

> hash() truncates the value returned from an object’s custom **hash**() method to the size of a Py_ssize_t.

To answer the question, we need to get this `Py_ssize_t`. After some research, it *seems* that it is stored in `sys.maxsize`, although I'd appreciate some feedback here.

The solution that I adopted eventually was then:

```py
import sys
bits = sys.hash_info.width              # in my case, 64
print (sys.maxsize)                     # in my case, 9223372036854775807

# Therefore:
hash_maxValue = int((2**bits)/2) - 1    # 9223372036854775807, or +sys.maxsize
hash_minValue = -hash_maxValue          # -9223372036854775807, or -sys.maxsize
```

Happy to receive comments/feedbacks on this – until proven wrong, this is the accepted answer.

---

<sup>[1] <sub>The note is included [in the section dedicated to `__hash__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) instead of the one dedicated to `hash()`.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

> `hash()` truncates the value returned from an object’s custom `__hash__()`
> method to the size of a Py_ssize_t. This is typically 8 bytes on
> 64-bit builds and 4 bytes on 32-bit builds. If an object’s `__hash__()`
> must interoperate on builds of different bit sizes, be sure to check
> the width on all supported builds. An easy way to do this is with
> `python -c "import sys; print(sys.hash_info.width)`".

More details can be found here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__