# RSA MPrime broken when the values are too high in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

My RSA MPrime is having problem decrypting when the primes value are too high

My decryption code is below:

```
def descripto(msg, d, num, N):
    ds = []
    ms = []
    MSG = 0
    for n in range(0, len(num)):
        ds.append(d % (num[n]-1))
    for n in range(0, len(num)):
        ms.append(pow(msg, ds[n]) % num[n])
    for n in range(0, len(num)):
        MSG = MSG + (N/num[n]) * ms[n] * pow(int(N/num[n]), -1, int(num[n]))

    MSG = MSG % N
    return int(MSG)
```

N is the product of all num numbers (the primes). msg is a random number. d is the private key.

Some tests:

```
Primes: [1181, 1543, 149]
Phi: 269294880
Public Key: <271520167, 7>
Private Key: <271520167, 230824183>
Message: 132
Crypto message: 30346111
Uncrypto message: 132

Primes: [1181, 1543, 149, 2143]
Phi: 576829632960
Public Key: <581867717881, 11>
Private Key: <581867717881, 314634345251>
Message: 583
Crypto message: 424678919465
Uncrypto message: 583

Primes: [27361, 27449, 27481, 149]
Phi: 3054254636851200
Public Key: <3075227812833541, 7>
Private Key: <3075227812833541, 436322090978743>
Message: 108
Crypto message: 171382426877952
Uncrypto message: 44

Primes: [27361, 27449, 149]
Phi: 111144637440
Public Key: <111903781261, 7>
Private Key: <111903781261, 79389026743>
Message: 113
Crypto message: 38799834195
Uncrypto message: 113

Primes: [27361, 27449, 27481]
Phi: 20636855654400
Public Key: <20639112837809, 7>
Private Key: <20639112837809, 2948122236343>
Message: 19477
Crypto message: 4955135338363
Uncrypto message: 19574

Primes: [1181, 1543, 149, 2143, 7]
Phi: 3460977797760
Public Key: <4073074025167, 11>
Private Key: <4073074025167, 314634345251>
Message: 5
Crypto message: 48828125
Uncrypto message: 5

Primes: [1181, 27449, 149, 2143, 7]
Phi: 61606302589440
Public Key: <72457426388081, 11>
Private Key: <72457426388081, 44804583701411>
Message: 5
Crypto message: 48828125
Uncrypto message: 5
```

The encryption algorithm is ok, and the decryption also seems ok. I know I used a small variety of numbers in tests, but the problem doesn't lies here. It just seems to have trouble when it uses over 3 primes over 10000, and I guess it's because the computer can't handle such high numbers. Also, you can see "the apple doesn't fall far from the tree" when the decryption fails. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Is this python 2 or python 3? If python 3 you need to use `//` for integer division, not `/`. There should be no reason to use `int()` anywhere in this.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it's P3 but still using this changes (tested) there will return the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Python 3.8 or later (otherwise you'll get an error with the negative exponent when calling `pow()`.

In Python version 3, the `/` operator denotes floating-point division, which will give you a double-precision floating-point result. You don't want that.

Try replacing `N/num[n]` with `N//num[n]` (using the integer division operator `//`). And get rid of the `int` casts. They're unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes those numbers multiplied might exceed the maximum value for an int which is probably 64-bit. Yet in Python 3 the size for an int is unbounded so it depends on the machine. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604981/15545606) for more information.