# Program is not printing anything in the output

Tags: python, recursion

I've wrote a Python program to multiply two numbers recursively. The program is working fine for small digit numbers but when I am increasing the recursive stack to calculate the multiplication of two big numbers having 125 digits each (say) then its not working. The program is crashing and its not printing anything.

```
class recursionlimit:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_limit = sys.getrecursionlimit()
        sys.setrecursionlimit(self.limit)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        sys.setrecursionlimit(self.old_limit)


def multiply(x,y):
  
    if x<y:
        return multiply(y,x)

    if y!=0:
        return x + multiply(x,y-1)
    else:
        return 0
        

def random_number():
    number = rt.randint(pow(10,128),pow(10,129))

    return number


def main():
    x = random_number()
    y = random_number()
    
    with recursionlimit(10**9):
        output = multiply(x,y)
      
   
    print(output)
   

main()
```

Comment: Isnt Python Long size 9223372036854775807 or  2^63 - 1.  This is 9.223372037×10¹⁸  so I do not think you can use numbers > 18 digits

Comment: @colinpaice No, that is incorrect. Python supports arbitrarily large integers, limited only by available memory. See also [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7604966/11082165)

Comment: Stepping back for a moment, are you really surprised that you're running out of resources when making on the order of 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 recursive function calls?

Comment: Like Brian said, it's an expected behavior. Experiment yourself increasing number of digits like 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc.

Comment: If you already know that, then you should be clear on what are you asking for. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The program will crash as you're making 10^128 recursive calls which attempts to deplete system resources.

By default the maximum recursion limit is 10^3. 10^9 is already large enough to crash most systems. If one recursive call would be a simple 4 bytes, integer, you'd already take 4 GB of memory.

Unluckily for us, a recursive call is considerably larger than 4 bytes.