# How to write an BMP image in python using no external library?

Tags: python, data-structures, graphics, bitmap

I am trying to start writing a `BMP` image file with python without using any importing any libraries like `PIL` or `Image` just to learn how it works,

I started by looking up at the documentations and how `BMP` files are formatted from [this article](http://www.brackeen.com/vga/bitmaps.html) but I had no clue how to start, and what is a `WORD` and `DWORD` datatypes

Comment: Word and dWord are ints of the cpu/arch word and double word sizes. In a 32 bit system the word is 32 bits wide. Bear in mind that if you are using a 32bit low level api you'd most likely be using 32 bit words even on 64 bit system. More details https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

Comment: @Machinarius And how to use them in python ?

Comment: I really don't know about python but most managed languages define the int and byte data types as a word for the platform the runtime is compiled for (.net and Java do this).  This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/6918291/528131

Comment: A dotnet example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BR7cfs - 4 bytes * 8 bits = 32 bits, the word size of a 32 bits runtime